# how to hide a folder and everything inside it with batch files

Tags: batch

how to hide a folder and everything inside it with batch files

I have researched for a long time and I cannot find anything. I need help on making a folder *hide* as well as everything else inside it with a Batch file.

If you know an easy way to do this or any way at all that would be very much appreciated.

P.S I really just need to be able to hide everything inside a folder.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
REM make parent hidden
attrib +h <foldername>
REM make all sub files and folders hidden
attrib +h /s /d <foldername>\*.*
```

Further explanation not really required.